# How to store a simple SQL query into user defined variable and execute it in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-variables

I'm new to MySQL, I'm trying to store `sql` statement into variable:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_tableName';
  SELECT @sql;
```

It executes correctly, and give me result:

[image]

But how can see the result of the sql statement stored in that variable? If I'm execute it, it gives an error.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_defects';
  SELECT @sql;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
```

**error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getClauses() on
>   null in
>   /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Utils/Query.php:567
>   Stack trace: #0

Please any one help me to execute the sql statement stored in variable (Want to execute/check the result stored in that variable. I know we can directly run and check the result in SQL prompt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a result for that variable you have to first create a `stored procedure` and execute that procedure you will get the answer.

**Create stored procedure:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN  
SET @sql = ('SELECT * FROM tbl_defects');
  SELECT @sql;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Is there any way to execute it without stored procedure ?